# SQL Server turns off always after generate about 60 millions records

Tags: sql-server

I write simple script in SQL to generate data. But always after generates 60 
millions records SQL Server Management Studio turns of. My script use only 30% of my memory and 50% of CPU. I have SQL Server enterprise edition on my PC and I use SQL Server Management Studio 2017. Maybe there is some time limit that I have to change in server settings?

Comment: what do you mean by `turn off` ?

Comment: Check ERRORLOG file whether some related messages exist

Comment: There is a restart my sql servere management studio.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following solution work for you.

Right click on the database giving you the problem in the object explorer.

1. Click ‘Properties’
2. Click ‘Options’
3. Set ‘Auto Close’ to False